# Reverse Polish Notation- Logic and display of results

Tags: c#

I am working on a Reverse polish notation calculator. I created a method that will take care of the calculations but there are three lines in my code that are causing an error. After every `=` an operation is performed and then displayed. I am trying to grab the string from `TxtInputBox` and convert to integers but it always shows the catch message `Please check the input`. Then nothing gets calculated or display. I am sure that my first if statement will check for actual integers and avoid the characters. My ultimate goal is to input a formula in rpn format and have the result display in the multiline textbox.

**Sample Input** `5 6 -=`

**Code**

```
namespace rpncalc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RPNCalc(TextBox TxtBoxInputbox, TextBox TxtBoxOutputbox)
        {
            Stack<int> stackone = new Stack<int>();
            stackone.Clear();
            string[] inputarray = TxtBoxInputbox.Text.Split();
            int end = inputarray.Length - 1;
            int numinput;
            int i = 0;

            do
            {
                if(inputarray[i] != "=" && inputarray[i] != "+" && inputarray[i] != "-" && inputarray[i] != "*" && inputarray[i] != "/")  
                {
                    try
                    {
                        numinput = Convert.ToInt32(inputarray[i]);
                        stackone.Push(numinput);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please check the input");
                    }
                }

                    else if (inputarray[i]== "+")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                            int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                            stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    else if (inputarray[i]== "-")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                            int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                            stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    else if (inputarray[i]== "+")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                            int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                            stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    else if (inputarray[i]== "*")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                            int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                            stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

                    else if (inputarray[i]== "/")
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                            int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                            stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                        }
                    }

            }
            while(i < end && inputarray[i]!= "=" && stackone.Count != 0);
            string txtout = TxtInputBox + " " + stackone.Pop().ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            TxtOutputBox.AppendText(txtout);
            TxtInputBox.Clear();

        }

        private void Btn_Calc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RPNCalc(TxtInputBox, TxtOutputBox);
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the sample input

Comment: The first if statement can be shortened as `if ("=+-*/".indexOf(inputarray[i]) == -1)` which also is more readable. Alternative: `var operators = new []{'=', '+', '-', '*', '/'}; if (!operators.Contains(inputarray[i]))`

Comment: All other if statements can be replaced with a `IOperatorExecutor` interface and a `Dictionary<char, IOperatorExecutor>`

Comment: @jgauffin after adding `if ("=+-*/".indexOf(inputarray[i]) == -1)` i get error message: `string does not contain a definition for 'indexOf' and no extension method 'indexOf' accepting a first argument of type string could be found`

Comment: sorry, typo. Capital `I`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing to increment `i` after each iteration of your `do` loop?  I tried out your code and it seems like `i` is never incremented.  Also, when you catch and run

```
catch
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please check the input");
}
```

You could perhaps change it to:

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
}
```

so you could be sure of just what you're catching, and why.

**Edit:**

Here's my version of your code, now working correctly:

- `i` is incremented in each iteration
- Fixed the typo in the minus, multiplication and division operators that made them do addition instead
- Removed the redundant addition operator

```cs
namespace rpncalc {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        public Form1 () {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RPNCalc (TextBox TxtBoxInputbox, TextBox TxtBoxOutputbox) {
            Stack<int> stackone = new Stack<int>();
            stackone.Clear();
            string[] inputarray = TxtBoxInputbox.Text.Split();
            int end = inputarray.Length - 1;
            int numinput;
            int i = 0;

            do {
                if (inputarray[i] != "=" && inputarray[i] != "+" && inputarray[i] != "-" && inputarray[i] != "*" && inputarray[i] != "/") {
                    try {
                        numinput = Convert.ToInt32(inputarray[i]);
                        stackone.Push(numinput);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                    }
                } else if (inputarray[i] == "+") {
                    try {
                        int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                        int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                        stackone.Push(store2 + store1);
                    } catch {
                    }
                } else if (inputarray[i] == "-") {
                    try {
                        int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                        int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                        stackone.Push(store2 - store1);
                    } catch {
                    }
                } else if (inputarray[i] == "*") {
                    try {
                        int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                        int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                        stackone.Push(store2 * store1);
                    } catch {
                    }
                } else if (inputarray[i] == "/") {
                    try {
                        int store1 = stackone.Pop();
                        int store2 = stackone.Pop();
                        stackone.Push(store2 / store1);
                    } catch {
                    }
                }
            }
            while (i++ < end && inputarray[i] != "=" && stackone.Count != 0);
            string txtout = TxtInputBox.Text + " " + stackone.Pop().ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
            TxtOutputBox.AppendText(txtout);
            TxtInputBox.Clear();

        }

        private void Btn_Calc_Click (object sender, EventArgs e) {
            RPNCalc(TxtInputBox, TxtOutputBox);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good observation. I have now added `i++` after the last `if else` statement but it is returning unusual results

Comment: Your minus, division, and multiplication operators are wrong (copy paste issue probably) and `txtout` should start with `TxtInputBox.Text`, not `TxtInputBox`

Comment: @John You're right!  The minus operator was doing addition, and the output box was showing `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: 5 6 -= 6` instead of the expected output: `5 6 - = -1`

Comment: @charliecodex23 and you have a redundant check for `"+"` but you've probably found that by now

Comment: @John Yes! your suggestions fixed the issue

Comment: Glad you got it worked out! Edited the reply above to you instead of Danny (my bad)

Answer (score 2):

The Split command, with no argument, is splitting the string on spaces and other whitespace.

There is no space in the input between -= so it is treated as one token that doesn't match the tests in the if statement.

Original answer incorrectly suggested that Split with no argument was splitting into individual characters.

Comment: The former is not true. .Split() with null argument implicitly delimits whitespaces. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx

Comment: +1 For correcting your answer. Can you please help me correct that issue with the split in my code?

Comment: @charliecodex23 just change `-=` to `- =` so it splits them apart, unless that was a typo

Comment: Alright I made the change and it still displays the catch message.